# How can I eliminate the subquery to simplify my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have three phone servers pushing the status of their extensions into MySQL on a regular basis.  These systems are duplicates of each other in different geographic regions, but with the ability to fail over as needed.  Therefore they will report the same extensions but only one of the three systems will show the extension is registered ("OK") at any one time.

For example, table is as follows:

```
+----------------+---------+----------+
| extension name | status  | systemid |
+----------------+---------+----------+
| 101            | OK      | PBX01    |
| 101            | UNKNOWN | PBX02    |
| 101            | UNKNOWN | PBX03    |
| 202            | UNKNOWN | PBX01    |
| 202            | OK      | PBX02    |
| 202            | UNKNOWN | PBX03    |
| 303            | UNKNOWN | PBX01    |
| 303            | UNKNOWN | PBX02    |
| 303            | OK      | PBX03    |
| 404            | UNKNOWN | PBX01    |
| 404            | UNKNOWN | PBX02    |
| 404            | UNKNOWN | PBX03    |
+----------------+---------+----------+
```

So extension 101 is registered to PBX01, 202 to PBX02, 303 to PBX03, and 404 is not registered to any PBX.  No extension can be registered to more than one PBX at a time.

An OK status would be the "best" status and therefore the one I would wish to report, provided it exists.  However if there is an extension such as 404 that is not registered to any PBX I need to report that fact too.

My desired output:

```
+----------------+---------+----------+
| extension name | status  | systemid |
+----------------+---------+----------+
| 101            | OK      | PBX01    |
| 202            | OK      | PBX02    |
| 303            | OK      | PBX03    |
| 404            | UNKNOWN |          |
+----------------+---------+----------+
```

I have come up with the following query which delivers the result I want:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM table
     ORDER BY extension,status) AS dummytable
     GROUP BY extension
```

However this query is too complex for my web application.  I wish to create a view with the results of this query, however I cannot create a view with a subquery in the FROM clause.

I tried creating two views: one containing the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY extension,status
```

and a second view containing:

```
SELECT * FROM view1 GROUP BY extension
```

However the results are invalid as they seem to ignore the ORDER BY in view1.

I also looked into a stored procedure however that doesn't work with my web application either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is the query too complex for your web application?  In any case, can you wrap it in a stored procedure and call that from your app?

Comment: Don't use views in MySQL unless you really really have to.  The query optimizer is lousy at dealing with them, especially once you start joining against them.

Comment: Your query won't guarantee the output.  Even if MySQL supported analytics, it'd require a derived table/inline view.  Your query isn't a subquery...

Comment: The web application is presenting the data in table format and it is crashing when attempting to determine the counts of pagination purposes.

Comment: I created a stored procedure but the web app seemed to hate that query also.  I think if I can find some way to get this into a view, I will be home free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join it to itself. To replicate the results of the query that you said worked and gave you your desired results:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.extension
    , IFNULL(t2.status, t1.status) AS status
    , IFNULL(t2.systemid, t1.systemid) AS systemid
FROM pbx AS t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    pbx AS t2
    ON t1.extension = t2.extension
        AND t2.status = 'OK'
GROUP BY t1.extension, t2.status
ORDER BY t1.extension
```

I did not create the query above based on the desired output you provided, because the `systemid` column in the output you posted didn't have a value for extension 404.

Comment: This query seems to work perfectly and delivers identical (correct) results to the one I had.  It's quite a bit slower (about 2.05 seconds for this query vs 0.008 seconds for mine) but it gets the job done for my immediate need.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @jjj916, yes it's a somewhat expected result.. joining can be sometimes expensive in terms of performance.. but to avoid using a subquery of any form, it was what I could think of.. I hope it will be manageable somehow..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the order by to the second view?

```
SELECT * FROM view1 GROUP BY extension ORDER BY extension
```

Here's another more complex option that I know will work in SQL Server, but am unsure about in mysql. This one fetches the OK extensions and then those extensions with no PBX (this is accomplished by selecting any extension that has a count of 3 to match the number of your extensions):

```
SELECT ExtensionName ,
       STATUS ,
       PBX
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE STATUS = 'OK'

 UNION

SELECT ExtensionName ,
       'UNKNOWN' ,
       ''
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE STATUS = 'UNKNOWN'
GROUP BY ExtensionName
HAVING COUNT(1) = 3

ORDER BY ExtensionName
```

If that syntax doesn't work in MySql or is too reliant on each extension being registered for each pbx and there being a total of 3 pbxs, the second select statement could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT ExtensionName ,
       'Unknown' ,
       ''
  FROM [TABLE]
 WHERE STATUS = 'UNKNOWN'
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM TABLE t1
                   WHERE t1.ExtensionName = ExtensionName
                     AND STATUS = 'OK')
```

or:

```
SELECT ExtensionName ,
       'Unknown' ,
       ''
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE STATUS = 'UNKNOWN'
   AND ExtensionName NOT IN (SELECT ExtensionName
                               FROM TABLE
                              WHERE STATUS = 'OK')
```

Comment: This query returns invalid data, as I am always seeking the OK answer if one exists for a given extension.  This query seems to return arbitrary results.

Comment: Do you have a separate table that contains the list of PBXs?

Comment: I'm not clear on SELECTing 'Unknown' would work.  Each extension will always have a PBX attached to it in the table.  My desired output showed a blank PBX next to the unregistered line 404 but that could easily be handled by application logic.  I am open to creating a small table with three entries for the list of PBXs if it is helpful.

Comment: This logic was based off the first table in the question where you show extension 404 listed 3 times, but all of it's statuses are unknown. Then in the next table, you show that 404 should be reported with blank for the PBX. This is what the second query for unknown does: retrieves the extensions where there is no OK status for any of the PBXs. Did I misunderstand the logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both the GROUP BY and ORDER BY in one query.

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY extension ORDER BY extension, status
```

Comment: This query also returns invalid data, similar to the query proposed by competent_tech.  I need the OK answer in every circumstance where it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you only want the correct answers, this covers the states you've described:

```
select systemid, extension, status from test where status='OK' or (status='UNKNOWN' and systemid is null);
```

assuming that an unknown condition for an unknown extension creates null, if it creates an empty string, test accordingly.

Comment: Each possible extension will appear three times in the table - one for each PBX.  The query here returns all of the OK extensions but would not retrieve extension 404, for example.  The extension that is not registered anywhere is perhaps the most important data I need to show.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select column dynamically on condition on other column. I think this query will work.

```
Select 
    extension name, 
    status, 
    CASE 
        WHEN status ='OK' THEN systemid 
        ELSE NULL END
From table
ORDER BY status
GROUP BY extension
```

I havn't executed it. Please suggest if any problems are present with this query.

Comment: This one doesn't want to run with the ORDER BY clause ahead of GROUP BY.  When I reverse the order of the two I get invalid results.